# How can I use orginal javascript Web APIs inside react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I quickly create a react app by create-react-app,

When I call `new ImageCapture` inside componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
}
```

It shows

> ReferenceError: imageCapture is not defined

Don't know is it eslint block my call or something else

I've test this function in plain JS and it's work. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `imageCapture` using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)/[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)/[`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Without using a declaration you are defining the variable to be global which will throw a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

E.g.

`const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track)`